# Publish all Android App Bundles to Playstore command line

Tags: android, automation, bundles

Problem: 
Automation of application uploading after successful promotions. Typically easily done with APK and using gradlew scripts.

However, since App bundles are clearly the direction of the future and have many benefits we are moving to deploying with app bundles. We do not want to upload these manually.

I was wondering if anyone has run into this issue and how they resolved it? Initially, I hoping for a gradle wrapper script but I don't believe this will be available for awhile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The route I'm currently heading is leading me to write a custom script to deploy using this following api.

https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/edits/bundles/upload

Edit: https://fastlane.tools

I ended up choosing fastlane for now for simplicity and its robust reputation. Had aab uploading done in a matter of minutes. So far highly recommend.

EDIT: Ultimately, I ended up letting fastlane only handle aab uploads by getting the latest artifact from the successful build and moving it into an empty fastlane project. From there it requires minimum parameters/variables to be able to successfully deploy to google play WITHOUT needing to integrate fastlane into your Android Studio project.